# \ getting appended in the JSON response. How should i remove this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jsonp, getjson

```
{
  "content": "{\"text\":\"Executing NodeDatasetFileOrDirectoryCSV : 1\",\"id\":1,\"name\":\"CSV\",\"type\":\"text\"}"
}
```

`\` tag is getting appended after everything.

I want to access the type field. But i am not able to even after `content.type` because of the `\` appended after every element. How to remove this ?

Comment: Whichever web service you're using is improperly encoding the JSON and instead escaping the quotes. If you're using PHP, this can be fixed via `stripslashes()`

Comment: Looks like `content` is also a JSON string and needs to be `JSON.parse`'d to get a Javascript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're response is coming down as a valid JSON object, but the `content` property holds a value that is a *JSON string*, not a JSON object. You can either fix it on your server-side however you are constructing your response, or you can use `JSON.parse` to parse the `content` JSON string into a full-fledged object in JavaScript after you get your response.

The latter would be something like this:

```
var response = {"content": "{\"text\":\"Executing NodeDatasetFileOrDirectoryCSV : 1\",\"id\":1,\"name\":\"CSV\",\"type\":\"text\"}" };
response.content = JSON.parse(response.content);
console.log(response.content.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse() to get the JSON object from the string and then get the values using keys.